# How to instruct `splitCsv` to split by any whitespaces

Tags: nextflow

```
workflow parse_sample {
    take:
    samplesheet // file: /path/to/samplesheet.csv

    main:
    Channel.fromPath( samplesheet )
        .splitCsv ( header:true, sep:'\t' ) 
        .map { create_fastq_channel(it) }   //       [test1, [stlfr1, stlfr2, pf1, pf2]]
        //.view()
        .set { reads }                      
    emit: reads   
}
```

above is my current script. how to split by not only tab, but also any kinds of whitespaces (like tabs and/or one or multiple spaces etc)

Comment: I don’t think you can, and what you’re describing is also patently not CSV. Is there no way you can fix the input format to be actually CSV or TSV? If not, one possibility would be to reformat the sample sheet with a little script *in the workflow* before parsing it via `splitCsv` (something as simple as shelling out to (GNU) `sed 's/[[:space:]]\+/ /g'` should work).

Comment: @KonradRudolph Thanks for the advice. Do you mean I add "sed -i 's/[[:space:]]\+/ /g' $samplesheet" below main and above Channel.fromPath? But I got all null for my reads channel after doing this.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Say if I use a process toCsv(samplesheet).set {ch_csvInput}, how can I convert this csvInput channel to a file and pass it to splitCsv?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
main:
    toCsv(samplesheet)
        .splitCsv ( header:true, sep:'\t' ) 
        .map { create_fastq_channel(it) }  
        //.view()
        .set { reads }                      
    emit: reads
```